# Is there an argument to MemberQ so that it will always return TRUE?

Tags: sets

Is there an argument for the first input to MemberQ which will result in MemberQ always returning TRUE?  It would basically be a constant for the set of everything, I suppose.

Comment: Just a side remark: The "set of everything" is most likely not a set. ;)

Comment: I had a feeling I was taking some liberty with that phrase, but I figured MMA experts would know what I meant.

Comment: This is backwards, but `! MemberQ[{}, anything]` seems to always give True

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such argument that I know of, but you could make one pretty easily:

```
In[30]:= foo /: MemberQ[foo, ___] := True
Protect[foo];

In[32]:= MemberQ[foo, 1]

Out[32]= True

In[33]:= MemberQ[foo, _?NumericQ]

Out[33]= True
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for my application.  Thank you!

Comment: Slight tweak: `all /: MemberQ[all, ___] = True;` I used `all` since `All` is already defined.